# Oracle replace a character not followed by another character

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I am attempting to replace all of the `&`'s in a string with `&amp` unless the `&` is followed by `lt`, `apos`, `gt` or `quot`.

Running this statement

```
select 
    regexp_replace('&lt &apos &gt &quot &','&(^lt|^gt|^quot|^apos)','&amp')
```

however results in no changes to the string.

The output I would be looking for is

```
'&lt &apos &gt &quot &amp'
```

Comment: Is '&ltr' OK (stay as is), or does 'lt' have to be followed by space and otherwise the & should be replaced? Or should '&lt' be left unchanged if it is followed by space or punctuation, but changed if it is followed by more letters (or perhaps digits)?

Comment: Yes &ltr would be fine, I would not want the & to be replace in that situation or any other situation where additional charters follow

Comment: In that case there is nothing special about `&lt`, `&gt` or `&quot`. They should then be treated just as `&blablabla`. No?

Comment: No if the & is followed by 'lt' or 'gt' then I dont want it to be replace. However, it's irrelevant if any charters follow 'lt' or 'gt'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A direct and efficient solution (but difficult to write, read and maintain) is:

```
set define off
```

(in case you are using a front-end that uses `&` to mark substitution variables)

then

```
with
     inputs ( inp_str ) as (
       select '&lt &apos &gt &quot &' from dual union all
       select 'Hello, World!'         from dual union all
       select ''                      from dual union all
       select '7 &lt 10 &and &&quot'  from dual
     )
select inp_str,
       regexp_replace(inp_str, 
  '&($|[^lagq]|(g|l)([^t]|$)|a($|[^p]|p($|[^o]|o($|[^s])))|q($|[^u]|u($|[^o]|o($|[^t]))))',
         '&amp\1') as new_str
from inputs;
```

**Explanation**: (partial...)  This will replace every & with &amp, with a few exceptions. The & will be replaced if:

- It is followed by the end of the string ($), or
- It is followed by any character other than l, a, g or q; or
- it is followed by g or l, which is then followed by a character other than t, or by the end of string ($); or
- It is followed by a, followed by the end of string, by any letter other than p, or by the letter p followed by the end of string, or .........

**Output** (from my inputs):

```
INP_STR                      NEW_STR
---------------------------- ----------------------------
&lt &apos &gt &quot &        &lt &apos &gt &quot &amp
Hello, World!                Hello, World!

7 &lt 10 &and &&quot         7 &lt 10 &ampand &amp&quot

4 rows selected.
```

(Note: I always include an empty string and a string with no ampersands among the inputs, to verify that the query works correctly on them too.)

Comment: Thank you! im gonna have to try to decipher this to understand it a little better..I was def not expecting that much code to be needed

Comment: I added a brief and partial explanation of the match pattern.

Answer (score 0):

These codes look much like HTML entity names, but the ending semi-colons are missing... making it less clear where a name ends.

In the following solution I assume that these entities cannot be followed immediately by a letter, a digit nor underscore.

When a `&` is followed by such a character, it is considered an entity, and not touched. Only the other `&` are replaced.

```
select regexp_replace('&lt &apos &gt &quot &', '&(\W|$)', '&amp\1') from dual;
```

The `\W|$` matches either with a character that is not a letter, digit or underscore, or with the end of the string.

Comment: I just tested this on my input data - it works fine, except that you are missing two commas (and, in your solution, a "from" clause). I will edit to fix.

Comment: Of course, this solution will work in most cases, and then it will fail on the text of this answer, where `µµµ` is part of the text - not by accident, but exactly because you were explaining how you used it!

Comment: Note also the OP's answer to my question. Your solution will replace & in something like &ltr. Mine is different in that regard, I believe it does what the OP wants. Yours can be changed to meet the requirement too.

Comment: I am not sure what you wrote there (I think some characters got lost?). Can you type those `&` in backticks?

Comment: I can check, but isn't `\W` for NON-word characters (meaning not a letter, digit or underscore)? If so, then the & in &lt? will be protected, but not the $ in ltr (because \W does not match the letter r). I'll check and test, but that's what I thought when I read it. Separately: where do you think some characters got lost? In my last comment to you? It looks fine on my screen.

Comment: I see your point, and commented to the OP about this issue. I rewrote my answer now, because if indeed *every* entity should stay like it is (even non-listed entities, like `&ltr`), then there are no special cases. It becomes much simpler then. NB: I now see I misunderstood your comment. I thought you meant "...replace & ***into*** something like &ltr...". I now get it ;-)

Comment: I don't think the new version meets the requirement either. It only replaces an & but it does not replace it, for example, in `&brother`. The requirement is that this should become `&ampbrother`. Like you, I don't see the point of this, but I believe the requirement is pretty clear (even if the reasons for such a requirement are less so).

Comment: I would not know why `&brother` would have to change, and `&ltr` not, but indeed, it is a strange thing all-together. A bad design from the start. The database should not have these entities in the first place.

Comment: To help clear some things up. Im am looking to  avoid replacing xml escape charters  (**&lt;** **&gt;** ect) when running an update to relace **&** with **amp&;**. 
The whole reason i did not include semi colons in my original statement is because stack was automatically converting them  to < > signs